# Unable to set value of databound DataGridView added column

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a DataGridView that is bound in code behind, I add a column, then i need to insert data into that column based off column in the same row.

```
 Dim db2 As New MyDBDataContext
 Dim r = (From p In db2.EventConfigs)
 GridTemplate.DataSource = r
```

I add a column to the grid

```
    Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    col.ValueType = GetType(System.String)
    col.HeaderText = "SomeText"
    col.Name = "colWhateverName"
    GridTemplate.Columns.Add(col)
```

When i run it, the grid displays correctly with the extra column on the end. I run into an issue here:

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In GridTemplate.Rows
        row.Cells.Item(11).Value = "Does Not Work"
        row.Cells.Item("colWhateverName").Value = "Also Does Not Work"
    Next
```

Why is the grid showing the column, but the value of the column is empty.

Comment: The code didn't reproduce the problem. It works properly. Probably the problem is because of a settings or another part of code which we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Take out the item("colWhateverName") and shorten it to Cells("colWhateverName").

try:

```
   For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvReports.Rows
            row.Cells("colWhateverName").Value = "Also Does Not Work"
        Next
```

Comment: This has no explanation. Lean [answer].